# Flask Problem. How do I make send_from_directory() work?

Tags: python, flask

I've been using [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory) but it doesn't seem to work in my code. Can someone tell me what's going wrong? The problem is it doesn't download the file and instead gives me a 404

```
@pages.route('/download/<path:fileId>')
@login_required
def download(fileId):
    fileOwnerId = File.query.filter_by(id = fileId).first().fileOwnerId
    print(current_user.get_id())
    if int(fileOwnerId) == int(current_user.get_id()):
        filePath = File.query.filter_by(id = fileId).first().filePath
        fileName = File.query.filter_by(id = fileId).first().fileName
        directory = "/".join(filePath.split("/")[0:-1])
        print(directory)
        print(fileName)
        return send_from_directory(directory, fileName)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("pages.filesView"))
```

The output of the print statements are for example:

```
directory: C:\Users\AlexJ\Desktop\CloudStorageProgram/Files
fileName: img.jpg
```

idk whats going wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Windows. I see that you're mixing slash (`/`) and backslash (`\ `) in your directory path. Does that matter? And of course, does that directory contain the named file?

Comment: @larsks it almost certainly matters. Alex, you should use `os.path.join()` instead of adding the slash in yourself, in order to make the code work on Windows and other platforms.

Comment: And you should avoid using `filePath.split("/")[0:-1]` for the same reason. Use `os.path.dirname()` instead, that's going to work on Windows (your code won't) and all other OSes too.

Comment: Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html has all the functions you can use the manipulate strings containing paths in a platform-aware way, without you needing to know what the platform is. And there's also [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use) that I've come to like even better. At first it might take more reading to understand how to use it, but in the end the code is more concise and more intuitive to read.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working on Windows, you should be careful to avoid assuming the path separator is `/`.

Python has OS-aware libraries to handle path manipulations: [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) and [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use) are the two I use.

This line of code is not going to work on Windows:

```
    directory = "/".join(filePath.split("/")[0:-1])
```

This is how you can rewrite it using `os.path` (add `import os` at the top of your file):

```
    directory = os.path.dirname(filePath)
```

and when you need to join path components together, use `os.path.join(directory, filename)`, for example, although you don't need to do that here.

PS: Even when you're not working on Windows, it's a good idea to use `pathlib` or `os.path` so that your code can work cross platforms.